# No such module 'Firebase'?

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

[image: Why do the folders of my workspace still remain the in xcodeproj file?]

Why do the folders of my workspace file still remain in the xcodeproj file? In other words, Group "BrieflyA" and its contents from the elevated window(xcodeproj) should be above the "Pods" Group in the behind window (workspace), but instead it is titled as "BrieflyA.xcodeproj". Trying out the SDK [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase) shows that a working firebase project has all of those contents under the same xcodeworkspace. Could that be the reason why I am getting this error, because I'm trying to build it in xcodeproj? If so how can I fix this becuase I did a full clean and even started a new project, but continue with the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`platform :ios, 
'9.0' use_frameworks! 
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1`

- Have your podfile look like this.
- Run pod install again
- Try opening the .xcworkspace file through terminal
- Cmd-Shift-K to clean the file
- Cmd-B to build the file

That should fix it.

Comment: Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting end-of-input.

Comment: Just missing "end" after the pod